# Identifying "long and narrow" polygons in with PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, slivers

I have a set of polygons representing large areas, say city neighborhoods. I want to identify the large overlapping areas between them.

But there's a problem: sometimes these polygons will overlap along their perimeters (because they were drawn with little precision). This will generate long and narrow overlaps that I do not care about.

But other times there will be big overlaps of robust polygons, meaning large areas where a neighborhood's polygon overlaps another. I want to select only these.

See the picture below of just the overlaps. Imagine I wanted to select only the blue polygon in the lower right corner.

[image: overlap]

I could look at areas, but sometimes the narrow ones are so long they end up having areas as large as the blue polygon. I've tried to do a ratio of area / perimeter, but that has also yielded mixed results.

I've even tried using `ST_MinimumClearance`, but sometimes the large areas will have a narrow part attached to it, or two very close vertices.

Any ideas of other approaches?

---

In the end what worked best for me was using a negative buffer, as suggested by @Cyril and @FGreg below.

I used something like:

```
ST_Area(ST_Buffer(geom, -10)) as neg_buffer_area
```

In my case, units were meters, so 10 m negative buffer.

For narrow polygons, this area returned zero (also, the geometry would be empty). Then I used this column to filter out the narrow polygons.

Comment: Certainly the area/perimeter ratio could be used for this.

Comment: It's hard to tell where the distinct polygons are from the image, but doing something like this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/265233/64838 might work? Calculate minimum rotated bounding box then discard ones with small width or height.

Comment: You could also try using a negative buffer as described here: [How can I identify really thin polygons in my shape file?](https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/7hdofe/how_can_i_identify_really_thin_polygons_in_my/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try to create a negative buffer, if it eats thin polygons, then it’s good, if it doesn’t eat the polygon, then it’s mine ... :-)

run this script, having previously set 2/3 of the width of the linear polygons ...

```
create table name_table as
SELECT ST_Buffer(
(ST_Dump(
(ST_Union(
ST_Buffer(
geom,-0.0001))))).geom,
0.0001) as geom from source_table
```

Comment: in the end your suggestion is what worked best for me. I ended using something like `ST_Area(ST_Buffer(geom, -10))`, the -10 being -10 meters in my case. If anything returned 0 from that expression then I could filter it out.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of area/perimeter, it is better to use the area divided by the square of the perimeter (or its inverse).

This is also called "shape index". The square of the perimeter divided by the area has a minimum value of 4*Pi() (in the case of a disk, which is the most compact 2D geometry), so it can be normalized by 4*Pi() for an easy interpretation (normalized values close to 1 then mean that you have very compact objects and squares have a values of approximately 1.27).

EDIT: A threshold on the area would be usefull to remove the very small artefacts, which could be compact. Then the shape index would show better contrast. 
EDIT: in addition to this answer, the use of [ST_Snap](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html) could help you solve the problem before it occurs.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm unsure how ST_Snap could help in this case...

If I got it right, you're suggesting something like `(o.overlap_perimeter^2 / o.overlap_area) / (4 * Pi()) as overlap_ratio`? This is having worse results for me than just area / perimeter.

Comment: Now using `o.overlap_perimeter / (4 * sqrt(o.overlap_area)) as overlap_ratio` according to this paper, but still worse results (although that's hard to quantify what I mean by worse) https://www.isprs-ann-photogramm-remote-sens-spatial-inf-sci.net/I-7/135/2012/isprsannals-I-7-135-2012.pdf, page 183.

Comment: Thank you for this, I had never heard of the "shape index". I had always thought that using a minimum bounding rectangle was the best way to answer this sort of question. I found this, https://repository.asu.edu/attachments/111230/content/Li_Goodchild_Church_CompactnessIndex.pdf, which is interesting.

Comment: @JohnPowell intersting paper, thanks. I see that what I know as a shape index is called circularity index in the paper. My problem with minimum bounding rectangles is that it doesn't work with very concave objects (e.g. U-shaped)

Comment: @bplmp ST_Snap would help you snap the vertices of "nearly" adjacent polygons so that they do no overlap anymore. There is no scale on your figures, but your artefact look like lines, so I guess that you can use a tolerance value theat is enough to avoid artefacts but does not affect the large polygons.

Comment: @bplmp could you please show a selection of problems ?

Comment: Indeed. The circularity index doesn't work with polygons with holes, but, that is not relevant to this situation. The other issue with minimum bounding rectangles is that they have a higher algorithmic cost in terms of big O.

Comment: This is commonly known as the "thinness ratio". Search here, there are other questions and answers on this topic.

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to use the ratio of the area of the polygon to the longest line that can be drawn using its extremities. Identifying long narrow polygons.

`select * from polygons where ST_Length(ST_LongestLine(geom, geom)) < ST_Area(geom) * 4`

This works pretty well for sliver polygons. You can adjust what the ratio (what you multiply the area with) to suit your needs and projection.

Answer (score 3):

The next version of PostGIS (3.1) has a function [`ST_MaximumInscribedCircle`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_MaximumInscribedCircle.html) which computes the radius of the largest circle which can fit inside a polygon.  This can be thought of as the "width" of the polygon, and could be used as a metric to determine which polygons are "thin".

This can also be thought of as reporting the negative buffer distance which just causes a polygon to be eroded completely.

Comment: And where is the function that calculates the radius of the largest circle that can fit outside the polygon? i.e. the described circle?...

Comment: That is https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_MinimumBoundingCircle.html

Comment: The function works incorrectly as it has no common points with the described figure!!! that is, the plane of the circle is slightly larger than the figure itself - this behavior is incorrect...

Comment: The computed circle is a slight approximation.  Agreed that it would be better if it contained the 2 (or 3) points which define the circle.  If you really think it is in error then please file a PostGIS bug report, or at least provide a failing test case here.

Comment: I've never sent any errors found in the functions, because I think this should be done by the PostGIS team testers, I think that when the function gives an approximate result, it should be notified on the official page and of course it would be nice to get 2(3) common points in this example, as it is, but my perturbations are not directed at you personally, they are directed at the expected behavior of the function and the desire to make the code better for everyone..

Comment: by the way, the 1:1 mismatch is 0.02 meters... maybe it's some kind of additional effect in the buffering... maybe something else...

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like a perfect use case for [PostGIS topology extension](https://postgis.net/docs/Topology.html). The topology's tolerance parameter will determine how far you allow vertices to snap to other existing polygons, to cope with the low precision of the source data and to clean it.

In short, the strategy is:

#### 1. Enable the topology extension

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

#### 2. Create a new empty topology

```
SELECT topology.CreateTopology('neighborhoods_topo', 4326, 1e-7);
```

The third parameter is the tolerance, in the units of the CRS; choose it wisely. Ideally, you want a CRS where unit is meters. If the CRS unit is not meters, as with WGS 84 aka 4326, use `ST_Transform` to reproject your polygons.

#### 3. Add a TopoGeometry column to the polygons table

```
SELECT topology.AddTopoGeometryColumn('neighborhoods_topo', 'public', 'neighborhoods', 'topogeom', 'POLYGON');
```

This returns a new `layer_id`. Save it, it will be needed later. It will be layer `1` if your start from scratch, and incremented at every new call.

#### 4. Add all polygons into the topology

```
UPDATE public.neighborhoods
SET topogeom = topology.toTopoGeom(geom, 'neighborhoods_topo', 1, 1e-7);
```

This can take several hours for a large dataset, be patient. `1` is the layer_id returned earlier.

#### 5. Find faces appearing in several neighbourhoods

Find all faces from the topology that are present in 2 or more topogeometries. I will leave the query as an exercise. Easiest is probably with the `GetTopoGeomElements` function, then group by face id, and look at the ones with a count of 2 or more. Alternatively, you could create a new table with the cleaned geometry from the topogeom column, just cast it to standard geometry `topogeom::geometry`, and repeat what you already have now, but now with a clean dataset without the sliver overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this might match your use case: [Eliminate selected polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#eliminate-selected-polygons)

> Combines selected polygons of the input layer with certain adjacent polygons by erasing their common boundary. The adjacent polygon can be either the one with the largest or smallest area or the one sharing the largest common boundary with the polygon to be eliminated.
>
> Eliminate is normally used to get rid of sliver polygons, i.e. tiny polygons that are a result of polygon intersection processes where boundaries of the inputs are similar but not identical.

It sounds like you'd want to try the "Largest Common Boundary" option.

Comment: I realize now you were asking for postgis solutions not qgis solutions. My apologies, I don't think postgis has an equivalent function but I'll leave this up for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop function if exists has_line_shape;
create function has_line_shape(polygon geometry)
returns boolean
language sql
as $$
   with aux as (
      select
         16 as SHRINK_RATIO
   )
   select
      ST_NumGeometries(ST_Buffer(polygon, -ST_Perimeter(polygon) / SHRINK_RATIO)) != 1
   from aux;
$$;
```

Based on the answer by Cyril