# Remove strange artefacts

Tags: postgis, shapefile

I have a shapefile with only one polygon. There is something that I'd like to remove, some "almost line polygons" that are there, as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

How can I do that? I can move it to a PostGIS db or use Python if necessary.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316212/120129...

Comment: This solution will not work in this case. As I said, it´s only one polygon with those "sub polygons" inside.

Comment: The black dots are "sub polygons" as well (geometries inside other geometries). I'd like to remove it as well.

Comment: How can I do to split one polygon in many separated polygons?

Comment: Create a copy of your table and check the operation of the proposed geoinstrument on it, but it is necessary to set the distance equal to 2/3 of the width of your polygons of lines...

Comment: ST_Dump() function

Comment: It worked, and I'm using st_dumprings(). As I had a multipolygon geom field, it was necessary to convert it to polygon before st_dumprings, so i did something like:

    select gid,
    (st_dumprings((st_dump(geom)).geom)).geom
    from ...

Comment: The solution has been found, and that's good for you, success in your future work...