# QGIS - detecting narrowest distance within extended polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have an extended polygon such as this:

[image]

My problem is finding the narrowest distances between its northern and southern border and mar them preferably as the points.

I found some similar solutions here:

[Identifying "long and narrow" polygons in with PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316128/identifying-long-and-narrow-polygons-in-with-postgis)

but it seems to apply to "normal" polygons instead of the one presented above.

Is it some way of marking the narrowest distances within the extended polygon such as this? I would like to have them 2 - the narrowest and second narrowest if that makes sense.

Comment: double buffering method should work on all polygons, only it assumes its fine-tuning, i.e. for your case this method will "eat up" the narrow parts, but I'm not sure it will work for your case, I think it's right to first find the centerline for a linear polygon, then create perpendicular segments after a certain distance, trim them with your polygon, calculate their length and then choose the smallest segment from 1 to n...maybe I would use all the above methods...Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)