Removing polygons that look like lines in QGIS
I calculated the difference between 2 massive polygon layers with the Difference tool in QGIS. I get the result I wanted...more or less. The problem is that there are a bunch of lines that appear in the middle of the polygons of interest. I tried getting rid of them by calculating their surface and getting rid of those that are really tiny (0.001, 0.01, 0.1ha, etc.), but I still haven't arrived to a satisfying result.
Does anyone have tips to get rid of these skinny line-looking polygons?

You can check out different tips at this link:https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/316128/120129...

You might run a snap of one layer to the other prior to running the overlay.

You may use the "Roundness" tool that :

Calculates the roundness of each feature and stores it as a new field.
The input vector layer must contain polygons.
The roundness of a
polygon is defined as 4π × polygon area / perimeter². The roundness
value varies between 0 and 1. A perfect circle has a roundness of 1,
while a completely flat polygon has a roundness of 0.

Then erase the polygons that fall below a certain roundness (you may need some trial and error to find the exact value that will remove all unwanted polygon without removing "good" polygon)


In newer versions of QGIS there is a "Grid size" parameter available in the "Geoprocessing Tools" like "Difference" that can avoid the very narrow polygons from appearing altogether.
If you specify a value for this parameter, this will have the following effects:

Coordinates will be rounded if the precision grid specified is less precise than the input geometry. Duplicated vertices will be dropped from lines and polygons.
Line and polygon geometries will be removed if all vertices are closer together than the grid size or, for polygons, if they become significantly narrower than the grid size.
Spikes or sections in Polygons significantly narrower than grid_size after rounding the vertices will be removed.

Based on some tests I did in the past, using a grid size >= 0.00000001 (10e-8) cleaned up all lines in the output of an overlay operation for my data.
As there doesn't seem to be a tool yet in QGIS to apply this on an existing layer, I opened a feature request for it.


Another thing you can try:

I have two layers: A and B. I want to difference layer A with layer B.


Difference with A as input layer, and B as Overlay layer. The output have some narrow slivers:


Buffer the Difference output with a small negative buffer distance, to completely erase the slivers but keep the larger polygons:


Extract by location, Difference output as "Extract feature from", and Buffer output as "By comparing to the feature from" layer, to only extract the non-slivers from Difference output:



