Clean up polygon after difference tool QGIS
I'm using the difference tool in QGIS to remove a bunch of areas from a polygon representing a state. Problem is, these areas don't fit together perfectly, and the result looks very messy.
How can I clean this up so that only the larger areas are displayed, and get rid of all the areas that are so thin they look like lines?
Original polygon:

Polygon after running difference tool:


Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336131/eliminate-sliver-polygons-qgis-3 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409059/deleting-sliver-parts-of-single-polygon-using-qgis help?

What does the other layer that you are differencing represent? Can you clean it up before differencing?

@ Tom Brennan They represent multiple different things such as mineral titles and national parks. I need a way to clean it up automatically because it's updated daily. I can't do it manually

Have you tried the gridsize parameter of the difference tool as explained here? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/480057/removing-polygons-that-look-like-lines-in-qgis/480067#480067

@ Michael Stimson. Thank you. This was not exactly what I needed, but it gave me the idea of how to solve the issue. ran the boundary tool on the difference layer, then buffered the output by the width of the slivers, making sure to make the ends square and miter joins to retain the original shape. I then ran the difference tool on the original difference layer using the buffered boundaries as the overlay. I then rebuffered the output layer back to the original extent

@ Pieter Looks good, but unfortunately a lot of these slivers are actually attached to other polygons I'd like to keep. I found a way around this with @ Michael Stimson's help

@user240982 when you use the "grid size" parameter of the "Difference" tool it will also remove parts of polygons that are narrower than the "grid size" while retaining wider sections of them, so normally should be OK. But great you got your problem solved, there are many roads to Rome.

After reading the replies I was able to adapt those suggestions to this situation
Step 1: Run boundary tool on original difference layer
Step 2: Run buffer tool on boundary layer, with a distance slightly exceeding the width of the slivers I am trying to remove. Being sure to select square endcaps and miter join style to retain original shape.
Step 3: Run difference tool with buffer output as the overlay and original difference layer as input.
Buffer the new difference layer with identical parameters to how the boundary layer was buffered. This restores the polygons to their original extent.
Original difference layer:

After completing these steps:


Accept your answer with the checkbox
