# Bounding Box -- Understanding (setting) Unit of Measurement in QGIS

Tags: qgis, extents

**QGIS Version 3.4**

[My initial problem (width and depth of parcel polygons) was solved by this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93848/finding-length-and-width-of-polygon-using-qgis/344360#344360):

[image]

**However, when I run the process the Units of Measurement are unclear. (see below)**

Moreover, I want to be able to set (or convert) the Units of Measurement to Feet.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most tools in QGIS (and other/most GIS software) will create an output using the same coordinate system as the input. Moreover, the unit of measurement is the one of the coordinate system.

It seems your data is not projected but rather in lat-longs (maybe EPSG 4326) so the unit of measurement is in degrees. This unit is meaningless for distances and areas.

You would need to find a projection suitable for your area (UTM or else) and run the tool. If the unit of measurment is in meters you can then apply a conversion factor to get the distances in feet

Comment: It worked! I saved the layer in EPSG:102008 North America Albers Equal Area Conic, then ran the Oriented Minimum Bounding Box tool again and it looks like a recognizable number.

Comment: You can always test what units are used by using the `measure line` tool to measure the same length, and changing the units inside the tool until the measurement tool matches the measurement with unknown units.