# Calculating the straight distance of non-straight polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, distance, measurements

I have a GIS layer of bus stops (MultiLineString), which contain the paint lines that are painted on the asphalt.

[image]

The complete bus stop element is in a single MultiLine element. If I select it:

[image]

I need to know the length of the bus stop to know the total number of meters to act on the adjacent curb. Is there a method to achieve this?

[image]

I have 100+ bus stops. Some examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Longest side of the fitting oriented BBOX would suffice?

Comment: What about Minimum Oriented Rectangle, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/265233/16530

Comment: Oriented minimum bounding box, but in some of your case, it will approximate the length : https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#oriented-minimum-bounding-box

Comment: distance between the first and last point might work too

Comment: Yes, longest side of the fitting oriented BBOX should work in my case I don't need max precision

Answer (score 1):

The query I was able to make with the hints in the comments above and that worked for me:

```sql
WITH 
  bbox AS (
    SELECT id, ST_OrientedEnvelope(the_geom) as geom
    FROM mytable
  ),
  corners AS (
    SELECT id,(ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom AS geom
    FROM bbox
  ),
  distances AS (
    SELECT a.id, ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) AS distance
    FROM corners a, corners b
    WHERE NOT ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom) AND a.id=b.id
  )

SELECT id, MAX(distance) as distance
FROM distances
GROUP BY id;
```